# How are feature request questions handled?

Tags: support, meta

I was looking back through the latest 15 or so questions on Meta tagged as Feature Request and didn't see anything set to `status-declined` or `status-approved` or similar from the SE staff.

I know the SE staff isn't simply sitting around waiting to decline or approve such requests the moment they come in, and I'm sure they leave a lot to the moderators to weed out prior.

BUT...is there some kind of flag or something on their end that gets raised at some point?  What if a feature-request comes through that gets 25 upvotes, does it then send a flag to an SE staff member that it could be worthwhile to approve or reject at that point?

I'm just wondering if there is any real point in even bringing such a request up at all?  It doesn't appear there's much done on them other than a few votes and a little discussion among the mods and meta members and then they just wilt away...

Comment: Did you wait 6 to 8 weeks?

Comment: "Can't tell if serious" -- Here's one I did back in December http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/6792/i-think-its-time-to-update-the-we-are-offline-bsod

Comment: Wait, that was actually a serious feature request?

Comment: Not really, but still irrelevant.  Shane himself commented/answered on it.  I just figure if it is tagged as such then I'm curious if there's any timeline/procedure they follow to actually respond to these with either a yea or nay.

Answer (score 1):

In 6 to 8 weeks someone from SE will glance at them and then ruminate for an additional 6-8 weeks before making a decision and waiting a further 6-8 weeks before telling you what's going to happen. If adopted, this will usually involve an another 6-8 weeks.

You remember the Star Trek movie 'The Wrath of Kahn' ? 6-8 weeks is SE's implementation of Regulation 46.

Comment: http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/5823/integrate-cloudsharks-service as an example...

Comment: @TheCleanerthat has clearly passed the first 6-8 weeks and possibly the second http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/5823/integrate-cloudsharks-service#comment11716_5824

Comment: Don't forget that after about half a dozen of those 6-8 weeks, they'll remember that this is serverfault and that they don't give a wet fart about our problems unless they're also problems on stack overflow.

Comment: Good point, well made RobM. It's interesting that @Shog9 found the time to retag the question but couldn't be arsed to answer it.